# C++ for C# Developers

Tags: c#, c++

I know C# pretty well (self-taught, sadly) and need to do some C++ programming for a Windows application.  I have been able to find a ton of information for C++ developers learning C# but haven't been able to find much on learning C++ when you already know C#.  Has anyone come across a good rundown of the basics?

[MSDN has a comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b.aspx) but it is not very in-depth.

I can piece together several sources but figured something was out there - I just can't find it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why "sadly"? Don't put yourself down like that. I don't know a C# developer that _isn't_ self-taught. Many of which are _amazing_ developers.

Comment: @SnOrfus -- mainly because academia shun it for irrational pseudo-political reasons.

Comment: My first word of advice is don't try to learn C++ in the context of C#. Because C# is not C++ and C++ is not C#. That might be a stupid statement to make but C# makes it hard to do pointers wrong, and its very easy to do them wrong in C++, even with the tools that make it realtively easy.  I would add there are many things that the two languages share in common.  It basically is like saying an Apple and Orange are both grown on a tree and have seeds and thus they are fruits.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka, not unlike how C# developers look at VB .NET.

Comment: @Kyralessa Which is also kind of unfortunate. I think it's not so much a political issue as it is condescension towards the VB.NET demographic -- because most of the C# early adopters have a C/C++ background. My school used VB.NET for beginner courses though. They seem to think that VB.NET is a toy, and so shouldn't be as corrupting to the minds of students as C# is.

Comment: Just read Stroustrup: The C++ Programming Language and a couple of FAQs(+FQA)

Comment: My main beef with VB.Net is the the rules of the language generally result in less compiler error catching.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Politics isn't actually the main reason we shun it. The main reason is cost.

Comment: Just last week we had a runtime bug because a VB.NET program was passing a string into a C# function that required an IEnumerable<string>. That never should have compiled.

It manages to be the worst of both worlds between compiled and interpreted languages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481003/good-c-for-java-developer) (link now dead, [view archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20101109141527/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481003/good-c-for-java-developer)) on C++ for Java developers is very similar and should be useful, especially Mark Byer's post:

> Read these books:
>
> - [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)
> - Sutter's books - [Exceptional C++ style](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++s.htm) for example
> - [Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

Probably the most important thing to keep in mind is to **understand the difference in memory management techniques between C#/Java and C++**.

One of my profs came from a Java background and taught an introductory C++ course thinking it would be cake. Nothing he explained made any sense to anyone. He had had memory leaks everywhere. His pointer arithmetic was terrible. He never got to the OOP part of the syllabus (thank god). Virtually nothing he demonstrated would have compiled. He didn't understand that `char[]` needed a sentinel `\0`. Don't end up like him.

Comment: Pity that *nobody in C++ uses `char[]` then*, isn't it?

Comment: @DeadMG I can't quite see your point. Just because `char[]` is seldom used in C++ doesn't mean it's not taught or that it shouldn't be taught. `char[]` is still important to be aware of because C++ is a superset of C, and it's *imperative* that it's understood correctly if it's to be learned at all.

Comment: Yeah- a very very, very long time *after* they have mastered about every other aspect of the language. I'd rather teach new students partial template specializations and SFINAE. In C++, you use `std::string`, and if you have to interop with a C API, then that's what `c_str()` is for. There's no need for the programmer to deal with `char[]` or NULL termination in any of that. The C-style string handling is completely and utterly and totally deprecated for every possible use except interop with old C code, which is perfectly well handled by `c_str()`.

Comment: @DeadMG I never questioned or approved of the curriculum with regards to when or if `char[]` should be taught (if I were to go that far, I'd first question why C++ is being taught to first years at all -- but that's another story). My point is that if you're teaching `char[]`, you need to teach it right.

Comment: There is no such thing as teaching `char[]` right, because all uses of `char[]` are wrong. Your professor would probably have been absolutely fine if he'd stuck to C++ instead of C.

Comment: @DeadMG You're *still* missing my point. At risk of talking in circles, my point is that my prof didn't understand how `char[]` works, and that he was a complete idiot for it. I *know* my school is hilariously outdated. Despite claiming to be among the most prestigious CS schools in Canada, they still teach MFC. That's totally besides the point. Again, I *never* said anything about the quality of the curriculum, because I don't even want to get started about it. To say "there's no such thing as teaching `char[]` correctly" is just jumping the gun to mash two issues together and disregard both.

Comment: What's wrong with teaching MFC? It's still a great C++ wrapper for the Win32 API. It's hardly "jumping the gun" to say that teaching C strings to C++ developers is wrong. C++ is not a strict superset of C. It's a different language. Thinking about it otherwise is just going to get you into trouble.

Comment: You *will* see C code used in C++ whether you write C or not yourself, and consequentially, if you're learning C++, you need to learn C. As I've said, I *don't* condone it, but the fact of the matter is that schools generally teach C and then tack on C++ later, because students need to be taught things like OS design -- which, excluding BeOS and certain research OSes, absolutely require C. For that, you *do* need to understand C strings. Again, for the third time, if I had my way, I would *not* teach C++ at all to first year students, and for the last time, that's completely besides the point.

Comment: @Cody MFC is great if you need to work with Win32 for whatever reason -- but it's completely outdated in academia, because coding against Win32 API directly is an outdated notion, or at least a very esoteric one. There is no academic value to MFC as there was in the past, because concepts of UI programming can be taught much more clearly and generally with other APIs.

Comment: The link to the other question for java programmers is dead :(

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, there's not much about C++ that's basic, so I wouldn't get your hopes up. In addition, there's little you'll know about C# that's even remotely transferrable to C++, so I wouldn't expect any specific material to exist covering that angle. You'll need to learn from scratch.

Comment: That would explain why there isn't much out there.  After reading up on C++ it a bit it would appear that you are correct - it's a totally different world.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1, _there's little you'll know about C# that's even remotely transferrable to C++_ . I've learnt this the hard way.

Comment: As a quick point, I would say there's plenty of C++ that's basic.  Distinguishing pointers/references and C++ templates can make your head spin at first, but when it comes down to it there are still classes, `cout` and simple ways to achieve simple goals

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: You probably mean "slow and exception-unsafe ways to do things" like "array-to-pointer decay" and such things.

Comment: Nice completely unhelpful answer.

Answer (score 9):

There's no easy fix for this, C++ isn't particularly difficult, but its not easy for beginners.

I would recommend reading up on the basics of C programming (to get a grounding of the low level stuff you'll find), then learn the STL, followed by articles from the likes of Scott Meyers. [Here's one](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-835T#c634517819201978626) to get you started, as it shows how you should be writing modern C++, compared to C-with-classes.

Comment: +1: I'd add getting Meyer's books (effective C++/STL series). I've got them all, and they're awesome.

Comment: -1 for `reading up on C programming`. I think this does more harm than good and coveys the notion that C and C++ are languages that need to be studied together.

Comment: @sebastiangeiger: you miss the point that when one has to work with existing real-world C++ applications you will most often have to deal with C-like constructs. Hence +1, at least to eliminate your downvote.

Comment: @DocBrown Maybe, but I am on one of those C++ legacy projects right now and I can tell that my predecessors were largely just C programmers that saved their source files as *.cpp. I found that I am using a lot less `delete` and C arrays and other things that are discouraged in C++ than they did, which I attribute to NOT explicitly studying C. C is relatively simple, you can figure out pretty quickly what the code does.

Comment: nobody suggested the OP learn C and leave it at that. I should think that the STL makes the transition between C and C++ quite readily, which is why I put it 2nd. You still need to grok C, or a new-to-C++ dev will find a lot of things confusing, and possibly not be as effective. eg. A great C++ dev wants to know what happens when you perform an in-place construction, and to do that you need know about pointers and malloc and struct layouts.

Comment: @gbjaanb: There's nothing, at all, about the STL that requires knowing `malloc` and `free`. A great C++ dev will *eventually* want to know about them. Starting with them is a whole different thing entirely.

Comment: @DeadMG that's what I meant, a *great* C++ dev will want to know them. The OP might as well know what they are from day 1 even if his usage of them is minimal as he learns more. My approach to learning is to know what's there even if I don't use it as one day when it's needed I'll remember and be able to investigate fully at that point. If I don't know the thing exists, even by just rumour, I'm hindered when things get tricky.

Comment: Besides, a beginner will learn smart pointers and object scope first, but know that it can involve the new operator which involves malloc. I should think he will never use new or malloc, but it's best if he knows that's what's going on. A dev who leanrns only the smart pointer is like a 'VB dev' who sticks only to the very highest level concepts and which IDE button to click to get them - which is not what a C++ dev is about :)

Comment: @gbjbaanb: A great C++ dev will want to know them- a long, long time after he's done learning things like partial template specialization.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for materials, I found this article a few months ago.  It isn't a book (only 53 pages).  The introduction says it all:

`This is a somewhat short guide to the important things to know if you are a C# programmer and find yourself needing or wanting to work in C++`

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815091505/http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2012/02/02/c-to-c-ndash-a-somewhat-short-guide.aspx)

And there is also an update post too:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201201001903/http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2012/02/14/c-to-cndasha-somewhat-short-guide-update-1.aspx)

Above page now contains a dead link to a pdf version.
Here's the [archived pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809084340/http://www.bobtacoindustries.com/Content/Devs/CsToCpp-ASomewhatShortGuide.pdf).

Happy learning :)

Comment: Be very careful when using this document though, it shows C++ in a very Microsoft centered way (it also says so). It does not differentiate between C++03 and C++11 features, and sometimes even shows non standard extensions as the preferred solution. You will end up with highly unportable code if you follow that guide.

Comment: GeeksWithBlogs is no longer available.  The Wayback machine doesn't seem to have the articles either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey let me google that for you ;).  This might be the same article, it might not, https://docplayer.net/19663746-C-to-c-a-somewhat-short-guide.html

Answer (score 4):

- Look out for memory management. Get clear idea on how pointers and references work in C++ in contrast to C#. Also, RAII, manual memory management and smart pointers at last.
- Templates and generics looks similar but are different beasts. Know the internals of how templates work.
- There are some tiny but catchy syntactic differences. Learn them.
- You have get used to STL instead of .net BCL. You may going to miss some good bits if have LINQ addiction.
- There are some fundamental design difference between C++ and C#. So, you cannot just port an idea. Anything you build with C++, you have to design from scratch.
- Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good that you dont find too many C# to C++ tutorials. They may probably muddle up your brain. Its a lot like trying to learn riding a motorcycle first and then switching to a bicycle (not an entirely appropriate anology but you get the idea). It is better for you to take a fresh book on C++. Since you are already familiar with the OOP concepts you can either skip the lengthy introductions to OOP concepts( they are meant for people migrating from C to C++). Or go diretly for a reference book meant for begginer-to-intermediate or intermediate levels.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going to Rosetta Code and comparing the two. While you are there keep handy a link of C++ idioms and try to spot them. Then spend some time on the pointer/reference/memory/destructor realm. After that learn about the preprocessor -- it can really be your friend when it comes to hiding the uglies, I kind of miss it. Finally, the STL.

Answer (score 1):

So, about one year ago I was in the same boat as you: self taught c# dev who felt the need to learn C++. Granted, I stopped and started multiple times. On my third attempt, I finally stuck through it.

What is imperative to understand is that, in terms of C++ and C# methodologies, you will likely spend a lot of time understanding what data manipulation methods through pointers and references *really* means, as well as when and how to use them given the circumstances.

The nice thing about C++ is that object stack allocation is quite simple for the most part, and you should allocate objects this way if your program will meet the requirements specified under this method. Otherwise, you rely on pointers for speed, efficiency, and quick clean up. I recommend reading this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ as it will give you a LOT of technical understanding of how C++ works under the hood.

Let me give you an example:

In C++ there exists this constructor implementation known as an "initialization list", which differs from initializing class members in the body of a constructor. Why? Because unless the type being initialized is primitive, the compiler will actually create *multiple, and unnecessary* copies of the object being created when allocated in the ctor's body. This can potentially reduce performance, depending on the compiler as well as the scaled requirements of the app.

Know what a delegate is? Well, in C++ it is known as a *function pointer*. This language is quite difficult to master at first, but if you want to be awesome... it's definitely required.

C# is easy...very easy.

Comment: C# Delegates and c function pointers are quite different. A delegate is closer to a functor in C++ than to a function pointer.

Answer (score -2):

Believe me, Pick a good book on C++ (there are much more, just do a search) and start learning...

Comment: BTW, learning some C before (pointers, arrays, struct) will be good

Comment: Learning C before C++ will throw you back into the stone age. Nowadays, we very rarely use arrays and pointers in C++. The language has evolved away from them a long time ago.

Comment: Myself, what I like in C/C++ is the low-level staff it provides!

Comment: @Muhammad: Everyone else prefers speed, safety, ease of maintenance.

Comment: @DeadMG, When learning, I prefer to learn every single bit in the language and go deeply inside it, but When going to write prod code, Your words very fit.

Comment: @FredOverflow. I disagree. I have seen the fear many of my C# teammates have of C++, especially pointer and scop resolution notation. And they have leart C, C++ in college. If you are a sttarter it is actually better to start with C and hone your programming logic before getting into OOP. Learning both together may frustrate most beginners.

Comment: @DPD: Well, many professional C++ programmers, including Bjarne Stroustrup (the inventor of the language), disagree with you. His latest book teaches using objects and templates from the beginning, whereas arrays and pointers aren't talked about at all before Chapter 17 (page 500 and something).

Comment: @FredOverflow: "many" is a peackock term. I can also state that "many" professional C++ programmers agree with me. Im fine with you pointing out Stroustrups book but dont make yourself a spokesperson for someone else. Besides I have said what I have seen. Just because Stroustrup orderes his book differently doesnt mean that people havent faced problems trying to absorb OOP when they were just developing their programming skills. And a good number of C++ books still begin with a major sub-section on C before they get onto OOP.

Comment: All these discussions and no one pushs my answer up, oh no. :)

Comment: @DPD: They probably have a problem *because* they learnt C. The "C" part of C++ is the *problem* part that should be removed, like a cancer.

Comment: @DeadMG. Maybe, but you cant revert the C-> C++ evolution. If you hate the C part of C++ go for Java or C#. Personally, I found that concentrating on pointers and arrays in C before going to C++ helped me a great deal in my career. Sure , you can code a whole application without them but if you want the benefits of polymorphism you need to know pointers. How many of the important GoF patterns can be implemented without pointers? It wasnt the same for my friends who avoided the "hard" parts when studying C. Most of them found it difficult to understand polymorphism.

Comment: @DPD But C# and Java lack the cool parts of C++. For example proper value-type support + RAII and C++ templates are far more powerful than .net generics